# Cover letter for an additional attachment

Tags: letter, cover-letter

I have already sent an official leave request letter to a university official. However, I do have another additional document that would be good if I could attach it along with the already sent letter. Now I hope to send it separately along with a cover letter. But I have no idea how to write it, even how to write a heading for it. Highly appreciate if someone can give me a sample writing for it.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE Needy.  Please check out our [tour] and [help].  Your question unfortunately is off topic because it's asking what to write.  But you're welcome to stick around and read, answer questions, or ask new questions.  The short answer though is: to "title" it "Re: whatever you called the first letter" and say, "this is additional information to support my request from June 12, 2019."  Or something like that.

Comment: Cyn: Thanks. Do you mean to title it "Re: <Same heading in the previous letter>" ?

Comment: Yes, but sometimes SE does funny things with angle brackets.

Comment: Maybe the question could be rephrased as to whether an additional attachment requires a cover letter and how detailed should that be about the content.